# Python and stable API Segmentation Error (core dumped)

Tags: python, c, memory-management, cpython

I'm trying to Implement a K-means algorithm, with semi-random choosing of the initial centroids.
I'm using Python as a way to process the data using numpy to choose initial centers and stable API in order to implement the iterative part of K-means in C.

However, when I am entering relatively large datasets, I get Segmentation Error (core dumped), so far I tried to manage memory better and free all the Global array before go back to python, also I tried to free all local array before end of the function.

This is the code in python:

```
def Kmeans(K, iter , eps ,file_name_1, file_name_2):
    compound_df =  get_compound_df(file_name_1,file_name_2)
    N , d = int(compound_df.shape[0]) , int(compound_df.shape[1])
   
    data = np.array(pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(compound_df),dtype=float)

    assert int(iter) < 1000 and int(iter) > 1 and iter.isdigit() , "Invalid maximum iteration!"
    assert 1 < int(K) and int(K) < N , "Invalid number of clusters!"

    PP_centers = k_means_PP(compound_df,int(K))
    actual_centroids = []

    for center_ind in PP_centers:
        actual_centroids.append(data[center_ind])

    actual_centroids = np.array(actual_centroids,dtype=float)
    data = (data.ravel()).tolist()
    actual_centroids = (actual_centroids.ravel()).tolist()
    print(PP_centers)
    print(f.fit(int(K),int(N),int(d),int(iter),float(eps),actual_centroids,data))
```

This is the code in C, that manages the `PyObject` creation, this is the python object being returned to the `Kmeans` function:

```
PyObject* convertCArrayToDoubleList(double* arr){
    int i, j;
    PyObject* K_centroid_list = PyList_New(K);
    if(!K_centroid_list)
        return NULL;
    
    for(i=0;i<K;++i){
        PyObject* current_center = PyList_New(d);
        if(!K_centroid_list){
            Py_DECREF(K_centroid_list);
            return NULL;
        }
        for(j=0;j<d;++j){
            PyObject* num = PyFloat_FromDouble(arr[i*d+j]);
            if(!num){
                Py_DECREF(K_centroid_list);
                Py_DECREF(current_center);
                return NULL;
            }
            PyList_SET_ITEM(current_center,j,num);
        }
        PyList_SET_ITEM(K_centroid_list,i,current_center);
    }
    return K_centroid_list;
}
```

I ran valgrind on some samples, there were some leaks of memory but I could not identify the leak.

I also tried various freeing and `Py_DECREF` combinations and attempt to reduce the leakage, but to no avail.

Comment: Where do you get `K` from in that very first call to `PyList_New(K)`.  Is something missing from your code?

Comment: Not really what your bug is, but immediately after you allocation `current_center`, you want to be checking *it* to see if it is NULL, not the value you had previously allocated.